# Storing html code in the sql database problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html

I want to store an HTML code in an SQL database. It stores everything fine except when there are attributes defined such as border="0".
I think single quotation mark is not an issue. How do i avoid this from happening.

The error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your strings, looks like [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) will do the job in PHP.

Answer (score 6):

Are you escaping the HTML before attempting to insert it into the database? Assuming your HTML is stored in the variable $html

```
$html = mysql_real_escape_string($html);
$sql = "INSERT INTO html_docs (html) VALUES('$html')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

The normal advice is don't concatenate parameters and code to build the SQL; use static SQL and pass data as parameters. All decent SQL APIs have parameter-binding mechanisms.

However, AFAICT, there is no such mechanism in PHP database APIs. Instead, it seems that you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape strings before injecting them into your SQL statements. Please, someone tell me that I'm wrong and that the PHP authors aren't that stupid.

Comment: There is a thing called PDO which can do this. AFAIK it's not in PHP by default.

Comment: So what do i use, when i want to print as normal HTML again. I mean sometimes the data appears as <img src=//"0 ....
Without the image being actually shown. Is there something like mysql_get_back_original_form_of_the_string()

Comment: This should never happen. It's difficult to provide any advice, however, without seeing some relevant snippets of code.

Comment: @Zack - Escaped strings aren't stored in the database escaped. When you query the database you'll get your string back unescaped. This may be helpful to you http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php